# How to upgrade a SharePoint 2010 Project to SharePoint 2013 (WebParts, MasterPage, App Page, User Controls) in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, web-parts

We have a SharePoint 2010 project solution which we are trying to uprgade to SharePoint 2013. This includes webparts, application pages, user controls, masterpage, etc.

Foll. is the procedure we follow, please add to it/comment if we have missed out anything:-

1. Open your project solution file by right clicking and choose open with VS2012.
2. Edit your .csproj file and add to it -> `<TargetOfficeVersion>15.0</TargetOfficeVersion>`
3. Go to VS2012 and reload you project, Go to project properties and set framework as 4.5
4. Go to package and under properties of the package set the version to 15.0
5. Do a find replace for 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0.
6. Check each file to do a check for any hive references. You'll need to add a /15/ to these. EG: _layouts/ to _layouts/15/ and also for CONTROLTEMPLATES
7. For master page project make sure you copy paste the SP2013 seattle masterpage from Designer and use it in VS project.
8. If you are using AJAX control toolkit then make sure you use version 3.0.30930.28736 as this worked well. If we tried using AJAX version 4.5 then the webparts do not work when deployed.
9. Do right click on project and Click Clean to clean solution
10. Build the solution, then Deploy your projects.

Please add to this if there are more points to be considered. Thanks.